# what is the exact version of maven in : FROM maven:3.5.3-jdk-8-alpine

Tags: docker, maven, dockerfile

I am new to docker, and I see this statement in the dockerFile.

```
FROM maven:3.5.3-jdk-8-alpine
```

What is the **exact version** of maven being used? is it **'3.5.3-jdk-8-alpine'** or just **'3.5.3'** ?

Where can I find the download link(tarball) for this version, I dont see it listed under 3.X.X

[image]

Comment: You will not find this version because is not the last of the 3.5.X line where 3.5.4 is the last version of the 3.5.X line...better use a more recent version of Maven 3.8.6 see https://hub.docker.com/_/maven

Answer (score 2):

The version of maven is 3.5.3

The JVM it runs on in the docker image is Java 8 on an Alpine distribution.

You will most likely want a newer image.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. but why am I not able to find a tz link for this version on maven's website ? even if it is deprecated, there should be one available right?
the download link on the release page takes me to the LTS page
https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.3/release-notes.html

Comment: I don’t know.  Don’t use this image.

Comment: Check the "previous releases" section at https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi - in the archives you also see the age of your version, giving more hints to not use it. The main download servers and mirrors don't carry outdated versions

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html This is give the list of existing Maven versions Download page gives you the most recent version The linked graphic shows the most recent versions of each line (3.5.X, 3.3.X) etc. and the archive link https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/ gives you access to all existing versions...

Comment: I have a question: why are some tags not listed in docker official library? https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/blob/master/library/maven

Comment: @chenzhongpu I don’t know.  Open a new question.